# Extract text from the second parenthesis

Tags: excel, extract, parentheses

I have a cell which contains texts/numbers within 2 parenthesis and I would only want to extract the second one.

eg. Name and id (username)(UN9867329)

Output: UN9867329

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Alternate formula,

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ")",""),"(",REPT(" ",99)),99))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the target is in A2 then this should work:

```
=MID(A2,FIND("(",A2,3)+1,LEN(A2)-FIND("(",A2,3)-1)
```

I arbitrarily choose to use "3" as the start number for the "FIND" function. But, that should put it past the first "(".

This should adapt to any length username or id and return just the info in the second set of parenthesis.